# Document similarity

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning, similar-documents

I have close to 50000 documents in plain text format.

Is there a way in which I can group similar documents together? Similarity mostly here is the content similarity.

Will transforming the text into a vector (using TFIDF) and running a K-Means (unsupervised learning) algorithm on top of that help? Are there any better approaches that could be used?

Comment: If the answers suits you don't forget to upvote and check.

Answer (score 3):

I did something similar a while ago. We wanted to classify several types of pdf.

- We first extracted the text of the documents.
- We created NLP features with the text
- Then added pdf metadata: size of the file, number of pages, name of the document...
- We then built a classification model with a few samples and did [Active Learning](https://towardsdatascience.com/active-learning-tutorial-57c3398e34d)

I guess that you could also do unsupervised learning but I like it more when you can do supervised learning.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach for this is LDA (Latent Dirichlet Allocation), which not only gives you the groups, but also a way to identify the topics of the groups by giving you the most common or distinctive words for each topic.